# Why my self-created managed property does not work in SharePoint2013 Preview

Tags: search, managed-property, 2013

I create custom document set with several custom column.When I run a full crawl in SP2013 farm. I now get two crawled properties for custom site column. e.g. If I have a site column called EmployeeFirstName and it is Text field,then I will have two crawled properties(OWS_EmployeeFirstName AND ows_q_TEXT_ EmployeeFirstName).

A managed property is automatically create called  EmployeeFirstNameOWSTEXT.This managed property works fine for keyword search like ( EmployeeFirstNameOWSTEXT :Ben).This is documented [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219669%28v=office.15%29.aspx#mps_map).

However , when I try to create my custom managed property at site level , it does not work. I try to map to both crawled properties individually as well as map them both. (OWS_EmployeeFirstName AND ows_q_TEXT_ EmployeeFirstName)  and did another full crawl , but my selfcreated managed property does not work for   keyword search like ( EmployeeFirstNameOWSTEXT :Ben).

Can anyone shine some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you see it happening on SharePoint 2013 RTM? Did you start full crawl? Did you start full crawl immediately after creating new managed property?

Comment: Also make sure that the new managed property has at least one item with data that can be crawled.